# Sparsity of $L^1$ Norm Regularization vector

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, control-theory, optimal-control

Consider a generic optimal control problem
$$
\min\limits_{u(t)}\int\limits_0^T f(x(t), u(t))\, dt + \mathcal{R}(u)
$$
where the evolution of $x(t)$ is given by a generic ODE system $\dot x(t) = g(x(t),u(t))$. In my case functions $f$ and $g$ do not depend on time. I used the following expressions
$$
\mathcal{R}_2(u) = \frac{1}{2}\eta\:\|u\|_2^2  
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
\mathcal{R}_1(u) = \frac{1}{2}\eta\:\|u\|_1  
$$
as regularization terms. Numerically speaking I used Forward-Backward sweep method. Consider the problem with $\mathcal{R}_2(u)$. At each FB iteration I compute gradients and use gradient descent method. Instead with the other expression $\mathcal{R}_1(u)$ to minimize the functional at each iteration I used MATLAB function $\texttt{fminunc}$.

Then I would like to compare the results to know if using $\ell^1$ norm I can reach some sparsity of the control vector. So let $u$ be the solution of the optimal control problem using $\mathcal{R}_2(u)$ and let $v$ be the solution using $\mathcal{R}_1(u)$. A first idea to check the sparsity of the vectors was to compare the two $\ell^1$ norms. In other words compare $\|u\|_1$ vs $\|v\|_1$. Using this method the norms are really near for certain parameters of the problem, instead for other parameters the $\ell^1$ norm seems to be lower. Another idea was to check entries inside $v$ if some of them are equal to $0$ or below a certain threshold.

Is there a particular method to study the sparsity or to compare the terms of the two control vectors $u$ and $v$?

Comment: To see how sparse a vector is just look at the number of nonzero components.

Comment: "At each FB iteration I compute gradients and use gradient descent method." Can you elaborate on that? Why would you need to use gradient descent when you're already using the forward-backward method?

Comment: What's the reason for using `fminunc` when your regularization term is $R_1(u)$? The forward-backward method should be fine. You know the proximal operator of $R_1$.

Comment: They are all non-zero since they are approximated. I mean some of them are really near to zero but not zero.

Comment: I need to use gradients to compute the update control since the functional is complicated and I cannot have an explicit expression for the optimal control $u$ at each iteration.

Comment: The proximal operator of $R_1$ shrinks each component of the vector $u$ (assuming that $u$ is a vector) towards the origin by a certain amount. If you hit the origin then you stop. So, when using the forward-backward method to solve an optimization problem with $\ell_1$-regularization, you tend to end up with a solution that has exact zeros. But if that doesn't happen with the optimization algorithm you're using, you could just choose some small threshold. (But it sounds to me like you just need a more standard implementation of the forward-backward method.)

Comment: I wonder if I'm thinking of the same algorithm you are. I probably don't understand the details of your situation. The forward-backward method minimizes $f(x) + g(x)$, where $f$ is differentiable and $g$ has an easy proximal operator. The iteration is $x^{k+1} = \text{prox}_{tg}(x^k - t \nabla f(x^k))$. Here $t$ is the step size for the forward-backward method. So at each iteration you have to evaluate the gradient of $f$ (even though we're not using gradient descent) as well as the proximal operator of $g$.

Comment: Ok so you suggest to use proximal operator instead of fminunc. Because I have also to try with $\ell^p$ norms with $1\le p \le 2$.

Comment: My algo is starting with a guess of the optimal control. Compute the forward propagation via state ODE. Compute the transversality condition and solve the backward ODE system. Then at this point if from the optimality condition I can explicit compute the optimal control let's say $u^*$ I update the old control value. Otherwise I need to use gradients to move from the previous point of the functional in directions which minimize that functional. I call this process gradient descent. I can do this for a certain fixed number of iterations or I can iterate under certain let's say error conditions.

Comment: For $p = 1$ at least I would just use the formula for the proximal operator of $R_1$, since it's a simple formula (each component of the input vector is shrunk towards the origin by a distance $t$). For values of $p$ between $1$ and $2$, there might not be a closed-form expression for the proximal operator, so I can understand why you might use an optimization algorithm to evaluate the proximal operator of the regularization term in that case. By the way, my background is in convex optimization rather than control / ODEs, which means it's possible I'm not fully understanding your problem.

Comment: I think I don't know what you call proximal operator. Is it the gradient of the norm?

Comment: If $g$ is a convex function, the proximal operator of $g$ with parameter $t > 0$ is the function $\text{prox}_{tg}(x) = \arg \min_u g(u) + \frac{1}{2t} \| u - x \|_2^2$. The proximal operator finds a nearby point that reduces the value of $g$ without straying too far from $x$. You can imagine this is a useful sub-step in an optimization algorithm. For many important penalty functions $g$, such as the $\ell_1$-norm, there is a nice formula for the proximal operator which allows the proximal operator to be evaluated efficiently. (Technically $g$ should also be lower semicontinuous.)

Comment: Ok checked also on wiki, now it's more clear what you are talking about. In your definition and also in the one on wiki https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximal_operator does not compare any ODE system as in my case. Maybe this theory can be applied also in my case or maybe not?

Comment: No. I think it cannot be applied in my case since the functional is non convex in general.

Comment: I've often seen the forward-backward method used to minimize $f(x) + g(x)$ where $f$ is smooth but non-convex and $g$ is a convex regularization function such as the $\ell_1$-norm. So if your $f$ is non-convex but smooth, I think the forward-backward method might still be effective. I'm not sure how much of a problem it is that your $u$ is a function (I suppose) whereas in the applications I'm familiar with $u$ is just a vector in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Numerically $u$ is in fact a vector in some dimension. The fact is that in optimal control problem you control the ODE with $u(t)$ that could be see as a continuos function like $x(t)$. Then when you solve it numerically passing to a discretized domain you obtain in fact a finite entries vector for both $x(t)$ and $u(t)$. That is in fact my case. To minimize the functional I use gradients wrt $u$ in the forward backward method. I cannot see if this can somehow linked to the proximal operator. Maybe we can discuss in another place? More directly? Is there a way? Using some examples too.

Comment: Want to have a quick Zoom meeting? haha. You can email me at daniel.v.oconnor@gmail.com if you'd like.

Comment: I'll send you an email to decide the zoom meeting date. Thanks a lot in advance for the availability.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume the problem has been discretized so that the optimization variable is a vector $u \in \mathbb R^n$. Your optimization problem has the form
$$
\tag{1} \text{minimize} \quad f(u) + g(u)
$$
where $f$ is differentiable and $g$ is a "simple" regularization term. I'll assume that $g(u) = \eta \| u \|_1$.

It is common to solve problems of the form (1) with the forward-backward method, also called the proximal gradient method. The iteration for the proximal gradient method with step size $t > 0$ is
$$
u^{k+1} = \text{prox}_{tg}(u^k - t \nabla f(u^k)).
$$
In words, we take a step in the direction of steepest descent for $f$, then we apply the proximal operator of $g$, which is defined by
$$
\text{prox}_{tg}(\hat u) = \arg \min_u g(u) + \frac{1}{t} \|u - \hat u \|_2^2.
$$
If $g(u) = \eta \|u\|_1$, then it can be shown that the proximal operator of $g$ simply shrinks each component of $\hat u$ towards the origin by a distance $t \eta$. (If you hit the origin, you stop.)

I believe if you use this optimization algorithm you'll obtain a truly sparse solution to your optimization problem.